# Qualitative differences between the 2-sphere and other n-spheres

Tags: smooth-manifolds, spherical-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

I'm looking for manners in which the 2-sphere (the regular 3-dimensional object we encounter in real life) is qualitatively different from the n-spheres. Of course it is the only one among those that is a 2-dimensional manifold, but I'm looking for something less trivial.

As an example, a qualitative difference between the 1-sphere (a circle) and the 2-sphere is that the 1-sphere is not simply connected.

So the question would be: Is there some property X - that doesn't in some round about way talk about dimension - such that among the n-spheres, the only one that has property X is the 2-sphere.

A related question would be if there is some qualitative difference between SO(3) and SO(n).

Comment: Conjecturally it's the only sphere with a complex structure, but for $S^6$ this is still an open problem. It's also the only sphere with a symplectic structure.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: That would be the kind of thing that I would be looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer, but I don't know whether it will make you happy or not. Since you gave "simply connected" as an example of the kind of property you're interested in, there's an obvious generalization to higher dimensions: A space is said to be [*$n$-connected*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-connected_space) if every continuous map from $S^k$ into the space can be continuously shrunk to a point whenever $0\le k\le n$.  Thus $1$-connected is the same as simply connected. Among spheres, $S^n$ is the unique one that's $(n-1)$-connected but not $n$-connected.

Comment: I think this does in a roundabout way talk about dimension. I guess my example of simply connectedness would then also fail this criteria.